# JAXB - Parsing different xml tags with the same name

Tags: xml, jaxb

For example in this xml there are few tags with the name response, and each response tag has a different structure.

How can I create one xsd 
or one classes schema for this xml?

Thanks!

```
<Student>
        <courses>
            <response>
                <courseRecord>
                    ..
                    ..
                </courseRecord>
                <courseRecord>
                    ..
                    ..
                </courseRecord>
            </response>
        </courses>
        <address>
            <response>
                <detail transaction="address">
                    ..
                    ..
                </detail>
            </response>
        </address>
</Student>
```

Comment: Hi, please write what you tried?

Comment: I can't change the xml structrue, I don't have control of the xml structure, this is response from 3d party service

Comment: @ShirelYehudai See [this example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm)